# How do I control where my firefox downloads go?

Tags: firefox, downloads

I am downloading Ubuntu 12.04 from an 11.10 LiveCD, connected to the Internet via tethering to a smartphone. (Please don't ask why...) I have discovered that I have not enough space to download it to my Downloads on the CD. How do I make the download go to my Micro SD card? (Yes, I have it mounted already.)

Comment: Rollback to 1st revision. On AU you upvote the best answer to show it is a good answer and accept it if it solves your problem. (and oops wrong flagging @ moderator :D )

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 13):

In Firefox goto Edit and choose preferences, under "General" tab you can change the downloads location by clicking on "Browse" in front of "Save files to".

[image]

Comment: You can also click the radio button for `Always ask me where to save files` and it will ask you for the path to save the file each download.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox go to **Edit** -> **Preferences** -> and under the **General** tab, in the **Download sections** you can pick the destination for downloaded files.